# How to limit map bounds in mapbox MGLMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm using `mapbox-iOS-SDK 3.2.3` and can't find any properties or smth like this to control the map bounds. I need to limit the visible area for the user. Is it possible in current SDK version?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to set the bounds for the map for example to display only one city. So user can zoom, pan and do regular things with this map but only in limited area.

Comment: Mapbox appears to have a built-in solution now: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/constraining-gestures/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built in to the current version of Mapbox that looks like it would do what you want. You **might** be able to get something like it by

1. Implementing `mapViewRegionIsChanging:` or `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` in the map view delegate
2. In those methods, check the current region. If it's outside the desired area, reset the map view to something inside the desired region. That is, as soon as the map view starts to move outside the region, make it go back.

This would probably work but it might make the view "stutter" if the user tries to scroll outside the target region. I don't know what your app does, but it might be worth considering (a) whether this is actually necessary and (b) whether there might be a better way to avoid whatever problem you expect than restricting map view scrolling.

Comment: Ok, as I see, the problem is wider and exactly the same as in MapKit. Ok, I'll try to use the delegate methods to resolve this. Unfortunately, it's one of the main requirements to the map framework from our customers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's an open source framework, so you could always look into adding your own delegate methods (maybe add a `shouldMapViewRegionChange` method) or other means to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I took the idea from [@Tom Harrington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37997712/388210) and implemented the delegate with the goal of seeing how much stutter or animation jankiness there was while keeping a user within a known Mapbox bound.  I upvoted his answer, but also wanted to share this example.

Here is a Swift delegate that fills out the delegate for [mapViewRegionIsChanging](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.2.3/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapViewRegionIsChanging:)

- the main goal is to test if the experience is still pleasing to the customer (yes)
- Can the delegate properly keep the user within bounds without calling the delegate too often?  (still needs to be verified)
- Uses Balboa Park, as a square Mapbox `MGLCoordinateBounds`
- Only checks if the customer scrolls *too far* north
- The concept of *too far* is checked by some tolerance, `epsilon`
- Checking *out of bounds* on four sides should be straightforward

  ```
  func mapViewRegionIsChanging (mapView: MGLMapView) {

    let viewBounds = mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds

    // Set the map's bounds to Balboa Park, San Diego
    let boundsBalboaPark = MGLCoordinateBounds(
      sw: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.71942, longitude: -117.15914),
      ne: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.74093, longitude: -117.13374))

    let deltaNorth = viewBounds.ne.latitude - boundsBalboaPark.ne.latitude

    let epsilon = 0.025  // Magic number for tolerance of how far 'north' we allow (in degrees); Q.E.D meters
    if( deltaNorth > epsilon) {
      mapView.setVisibleCoordinateBounds(boundsBalboaPark, animated: true)
    }
  }
  ```

This animation shows moving the mapView too far north of Balboa Park.  The stutter you see is real, but acceptable.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest that instead of jumping back to the original center location, you could jump back just enough to stay within the desired bounds. That would reduce the jump significantly.

Comment: I agree. And another good idea is to animate to the views' minimum zoom, so the customer can get the experience of reorienting themselves.